# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]My Android Studio is full of error android studio cannot identify libraries.

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0
```

Comment: install com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0  repository or chnage it to the version of you have

Comment: whats your `buildToolsVersion ` ?

Comment: click on `Install Repository and sync project`

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya my build tool version is 23.0.1

Comment: @CoDFather I am clicking on Install Repository and sync project but nothing is happening

Comment: Is android studio currupted????

Comment: My case is setting to 26.0.3, it's still display Install Repository and sync project, even my build verion is set to 26.0.3 also(I am sure 26.0.3 is installed in SDK Manager). finally I adjust all verion to 26.0.1 , all trouble is gone

Answer (score 140):

Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
        // instead use:
        //
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
    }
}
```

[See android documention for details](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#download)

Comment: This must be the right answer. This fixed my issue.

Comment: why this is not default on android studio?

Comment: Starting a new project in Android Studio, and having to run into this kind of trouble is very demotivating.  Could scare off new devs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with latest libraries to be automatically installed by clicking

> Install Repository and sync project

Go to SDK Manager and install your missing or **not** up-to-date packages from below tab:

[image]

After you select desired library, click **Apply** and wait for installation to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Replace 
whatever build gradle version with this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
```

Then Click on

Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import the project

Answer (score 2):

1. At first change your **`buildToolsVersion`**  version **23.0.1 to
   25.0.1**
2. Set **`compileSdkVersion`** 25

**Finally**

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

Make sure you update your **support repository** .
Then **Clean-Rebuild-Run**.

Comment: I used your solution and I am getting  Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:/media/anshul/New Volume1/Security/Company/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: @RichaSingh read this line `Install Repository and sync project`

Comment: 3:22:02 PM Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.1
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: i am clicking on Install Repository and sync project but nothing is happeining

Comment: @RichaSingh Restart your IDE #Invalidate and restart

Comment: I have done Invalidate and restart upto 5 to 6 times but nothing is working

Comment: @RichaSingh No.

Comment: kindly remove your last resource changes and then clean and build

Answer (score 2):

add below code in your **Project level gradle** in allprojects{}

```
 maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

click the link

> "Install Repository and sync project"

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems as you say in recently. And I resolve these problem as follow:

Step 1.
Create a new android project in AndroidStudio , and it can run normally.

Step 2.
Please make sure your project can run normally, and see the **build.gradle** file， then find the version code in build.gradle file. 
And my build.gradle file like as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion 24.0.1
}
...
...
dependencies {
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0"
}
```

And the correct version 23.4.0 is what you want.

If you can not solve the problem, you can change **compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion**.

Step 3.
Config the correct version in your build.gradle file and sync project.

Comment: You should always use the same version of build tools as the one you are compiling against.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will go (your_folder_app)\app\app.iml, which open your notepad software.
After you will find: 
and you change to 27 with your version, for example for me, i change to 25.

Secondly, you will change the build.gradle(Moudule:app) in your android studio. Red arrow show that you should to change.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twuLH.png).
Example for me:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo4B5.png)

Finally, you will click "Try Again"