# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+, How to solve this permanently？

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, repository

This problem can be solve by including maven repositories as answered :[Failed to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313573/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v725-1-0)
But we need to add maven repositories every time after creation of new project, so is there any other way to fix this **permanently**?

Comment: What are you targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion values?

Comment: 27 @ZeeshanZulfiqar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure added the new repo in root gradle.build

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

You may also use with newer gradle wrapper:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            google()
        }
    }
```

If you have used data binding in repo, then make sure you have added:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 version as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Repos need to add for every new project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix this permanently, you should add following codes in **init.gradle** (for more info about **init.gradle**, please check this site : [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```